# EF Fluent Define Foreign primary key

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, fluent

I have defined a set of Code First entities as such:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}
public abstract class UserType
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
public class RoleUser : UserType
{
    public string role { get; set; }
}
public class SiteUser : UserType
{
    public string site { get; set; }
}

public class Testctx:DbContext
{
    static Testctx()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Testctx>());
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SiteUser> SiteUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RoleUser> RoleUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(u=>u.UserId).ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<RoleUser>().HasKey(u => u.UserId).ToTable("RoleUser");
        modelBuilder.Entity<SiteUser>().HasKey(u => u.UserId).ToTable("SiteUser");
    }

}
```

If I wanted User, RoleUser, SiteUser, to each have a ID column named "ID" How can I achieve this while keeping the foreign primary key relationship to user in Usertype.

For instance if i declare public class Entity{ public int ID {get;set;}} and have all inherit from Entity, I'm left with a UserId and an ID field in RoleUser and SiteUser.